# New created wordpress by cloud launcher Automatic Update Failed

Tags: wordpress, google-compute-engine, auto-update, google-cloud-launcher

I use the Google cloud launcher to start a fresh Wordpress.

with the following VM :

Machine type
f1-micro (1 vCPU, 0.6 GB memory)
CPU platform
Intel Ivy Bridge
Zone
us-central1-f

It was launched with an older version : 4.5.3-1

I tried to do an automatic update. it didn't work, and showed

> The update could not be unpacked
>
> Installation Failed

I tried following tutorials on 
https://community.bitnami.com/t/automatic-update-wordpress-4-6-is-not-working/43814/4

> Connect to your server via SSH and execute:

sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content 
sudo chmod -R g+w /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content

Doesn't work for my case,

I also tried to use follow manual update https://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress.
Delete the old wp-includes and wp-admin directories on your web host (through your FTP or shell access).

using filezilla ftp , i get a lot permission denied errors of different file names.

> Error:    rm /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/customize/class-wp-customize-partial.php: permission denied

Please advice. how can i update this thing?
Anyone facing the same issue? 
Google should put back their own wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following workaround to upgrade your old WordPress to the latest version:

- Open `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-config.php`
- Look for `define('FS_METHOD', 'ftptext');`
- Replace it with `define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');`
- Change the permissions of `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs` to allow the server user (`daemon`) to make the modifications. You can do that by executing `sudo chown -R daemon /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs`
- Go to the WordPress admin panel and perform the automatic upgrade.
- Change the permissions of `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs` to it original ones. To do that, execute `sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs`
- Replace again the `define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');` line with `define('FS_METHOD', 'ftptext');` in the `wp-config.php` file

Hope it helps.

Comment: I can confirm that this worked for me. Thanks for sharing your solution! :-)